# How can I play a ringtone of device using it's URI

Tags: android

I have an array list having uri of all device ringtones. I also have another array list having the corresponding titles of the ringtones. I have displayed the titles in a spinner. How can I play the ringtones when user selects a particular option from spinner?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

Play Mp3 file from a Url without downloading file [reference](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/PlayMp3filefromaUrl.htm)

```
public class Test extends Activity
{
    static final String AUDIO_PATH =
      "http://yourHost/play.mp3";
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int playbackPosition=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void doClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.startPlayerBtn:
            try {
              playAudio(AUDIO_PATH);
                playLocalAudio();
                playLocalAudio_UsingDescriptor();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.pausePlayerBtn:
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                playbackPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.restartPlayerBtn:
            if(mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playbackPosition);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stopPlayerBtn:
            if(mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                playbackPosition = 0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception
    {
        killMediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void playLocalAudio() throws Exception
    {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music_file);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void playLocalAudio_UsingDescriptor() throws Exception {

        AssetFileDescriptor fileDesc = getResources().openRawResourceFd(
            R.raw.music_file);
        if (fileDesc != null) {

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDesc.getFileDescriptor(), fileDesc
                    .getStartOffset(), fileDesc.getLength());

            fileDesc.close();

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        killMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void killMediaPlayer() {
        if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```